# WordPress Infinite Loop

Tags: wordpress

I've written this code but cannot work out why it's triggering an infinite loop. I have hunted around for similar issues but nothing is clicking for me. Can anyone please shed some light?

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => 3
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="news_item">

    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/dummy.png">
    <h3><a href="#">Government introduces X Y Z for lorem ipsum dolor esters.</a></h3>

</div>

<?php endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did forget to increment the post iterator inside `The Loop`. This iterator points to the next post. Since you are not incrementing it by calling `the_post()` inside the loop, `have_posts()` will always return `true`.

A basic example how to programm `The Loop` and how to use `the_post()` and `have_posts()` is shown here:

> ```
> <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
> ```
>
> Some nice Markup goes here...
>
> ```
> <?php endwhile; else : ?>
>   <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
> <?php endif; ?>
> ```

(Taken from here: Wordpress.com, **The Loop**, *1 - Using the Loop*, [Last time accessed at 30.12.2015](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post))

Additionally a note to `the_post()`:

> Iterate the post index in The Loop. Retrieves the next post, sets up
>   the post, sets the 'in the loop' property to true.

(Taken from here: Wordpress.com, **Function Reference/the post**, [last time accessed at 30.12.2015](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post))